# Black Screen on Ubuntu Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, visualization

I am using an Oracle Virtual Box to run Ubuntu on my PC. Everything was doing fine until today: if I start Ubuntu, the virtual box screen is all black. If I change the display settings from VBoxSVGA to VMSVGA and restart Ubuntu, it runs correctly but I cannot enlarge the screen. How should I fix this?

Comment: A few questions will need to be answered to offer possible solutions: (0) which version of Ubuntu is being run in the VM? (1) have you recently updated the VirtualBox software on the host machine? (2) have you recently performed updates on the Ubuntu guest?

Comment: You probably need to install the Guest Additions CD so that you can change the screen resolution.